# Entity Framework multi-inheritance?

Tags: entity-framework, design-patterns, inheritance, entity-framework-4.1, code-first

I have an abstract base class `Contact` that has two subclasses: `Person` and `Company`.

I want to have a `Customer`, `Vendor` or other types that can be either a `Company` or a `Person` (all sharing the same primary key `ContactId`).

My question is if it's possible to inherit all these types from `Contact`? If the answer is no, is there another option of utilizing the `Contact` property from the PK? What's the recommended design for this scenario?

Note that I want an `Employee`/`Customer` etc. to also be able to be a `User`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How would you achieve that in C#? That is the first question you must answer yourselves because .NET doesn't support multi-inheritance so you cannot have single `Customer` class derived from `Person` or / and `Company` - you need separate `Customer` class derived from `Person` and another `Customer` class derived from `Company` but every time you see this you should know that you are doing something wrong. Also if you in the future find that you need to have Contact which is both `Employee` and `Customer` you will be ready to delete whole your application because with inheritance there will be no way to achieve that. Changing `Contact` from `Customer` to `Employee` will be possible only with direct SQL because EF doesn't allow that.

Inheritance is not solution for your problem - you must use composition (relations).

Comment: Also called the Strategy Design Pattern.

Comment: I ended up creating a `Customer` with a foreign relationship to `Contact` (which is either a `Company` or a `Person`).